# When I put a date label on the X axis in a chart using c3.js, I get the error Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate (NaN, 0)"

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I'm creating a chart using [c3.js](https://C3js.org/).

I want to put the date on the `X-axis` label, but I get the following error:

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, 0)"
```

Specifically, the following implementation is performed.
(If implemented as time-series, an error will occur that it can't be converted to a `Date Object`.)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x',"2021/01/01", "2021/01/02","2021/01/03","2021/01/04","2021/01/05"],
      ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150],
      ['sample2', 50, null, 20, null, 180]
    ]
  },
  axis: {
    x: {tick: {values: ["2021/01/01", "2021/01/02","2021/01/03","2021/01/04","2021/01/05"]}},
    y: {label: {position: 'inner-middle'}},
    y2: {show: true, label: {position: 'inner-middle'}}
  },
  line: {
    connectNull: true
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I think you are looking for categories : https://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can it be handled as date data when implemented as categories?

Comment: You can use any string, so if the string is "01/01/2021" it will prompt it